# Unitary matrix s.t $A=PDP^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I am asking to find unitary matrix $P$ such that $A=PDP^*$

given $A=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 3 & 3 \\
3 & 1 & 3 \\
3 & 3 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)$

I found that $P=\left(\begin{matrix}
-1 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)$ and $D=\left(\begin{matrix}
-2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 7
\end{matrix}\right)$

but I am not sure what to do now because the collums of $P$ is not orthogonal, so what I should do from here? should I apply $GS$ on those vectors in matrix $P$?

Comment: Yes, applying GS to the vectors of $P$ is the standard approach at this point.

Comment: Alternatively, you could take $P$ to be the size 3 [DFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix)

Comment: and if I will apply the $GS$, will I be still able to use the same matrix $D$? if yes what is the explantion for that?

Comment: Yes, you will be able to use the same matrix $D$. The key here is that the eigenvector associated with $7$ is already orthogonal to the other two eigenvectors. So, applying GS will give you two vectors that form an orthogonal basis for the first eigenspace and a normalized third vector that spans the second eigenspace.